problem with getting server status code from boomi
I am new to boomi. I have tried to get the server status code from boomi.
I cheked "returh http error" option , add set property shape { add dynamic document property name :httpStatusCode" and pass it to decision shape to check if status is 200. but it always fail . Any suggestion?
